# JOIN, WHERE and the QUERY

Tags: mysql

Here is the code. It returns table with 0 values in months where there are no data in database. Perfect!

```
SELECT YEAR(k.miesiace)  as                                    year,
       MONTH(k.miesiace) AS                                    month,
       IFNULL(YEAR(data_zlozenia), YEAR(k.miesiace))           order_year,
       IFNULL(MONTH(data_zlozenia), MONTH(k.miesiace))         order_month,
       IFNULL(MONTHNAME(data_zlozenia), MONTHNAME(k.miesiace)) monthname,
       IFNULL(SUM(zp.cena_netto * ilosc), 0)                   sum
FROM kalendarz k
         LEFT OUTER JOIN zamowienia z
                         on MONTH(z.data_zlozenia) = MONTH(k.miesiace) AND YEAR(z.data_zlozenia) = YEAR(k.miesiace)

         LEFT OUTER JOIN zamowienia_pozycje zp on z.id_ezamowienia = zp.id_ezamowienia

WHERE k.miesiace >= DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 12 MONTH)
  AND k.miesiace <= now()

GROUP BY MONTH(k.miesiace), YEAR(k.miesiace)
ORDER BY YEAR(k.miesiace), MONTH(k.miesiace);
```

But when I add to my WHERE clause this:

```
AND zp.id_artykulu = 9593
```

it ruins my code and limits output to only months where data existed instead of all 12 months. What should I change brothers?

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: The aim was to have output in 12 months period with 0 where no data in specific month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your `zp` in a `subquery`.

```
SELECT YEAR(k.miesiace)  as                                    year,
       MONTH(k.miesiace) AS                                    month,
       IFNULL(YEAR(data_zlozenia), YEAR(k.miesiace))           order_year,
       IFNULL(MONTH(data_zlozenia), MONTH(k.miesiace))         order_month,
       IFNULL(MONTHNAME(data_zlozenia), MONTHNAME(k.miesiace)) monthname,
       IFNULL(SUM(zp.cena_netto * zp.ilosc), 0)                   sum
FROM kalendarz k
LEFT OUTER JOIN zamowienia z
    on MONTH(z.data_zlozenia) = MONTH(k.miesiace) AND YEAR(z.data_zlozenia) = YEAR(k.miesiace)
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (select ilosc, cena_netto, id_ezamowienia from zamowienia_pozycje
        where id_artykulu = 9593) zp on z.id_ezamowienia = zp.id_ezamowienia
WHERE k.miesiace >= DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 12 MONTH)
  AND k.miesiace <= now()
GROUP BY MONTH(k.miesiace), YEAR(k.miesiace)
ORDER BY YEAR(k.miesiace), MONTH(k.miesiace);
```

Comment: Genius! God (or whatever You would like), bless You! 
Please correct it to zp.ilosc in 6th row and add  ilosc to subquerry.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure to understand your exact need correctly but I think your WHERE clause you try to add is misplaced. It might work well like this :

```
SELECT YEAR(k.miesiace)  as                                    year,
       MONTH(k.miesiace) AS                                    month,
       IFNULL(YEAR(data_zlozenia), YEAR(k.miesiace))           order_year,
       IFNULL(MONTH(data_zlozenia), MONTH(k.miesiace))         order_month,
       IFNULL(MONTHNAME(data_zlozenia), MONTHNAME(k.miesiace)) monthname,
       IFNULL(SUM(zp.cena_netto * ilosc), 0)                   sum
FROM kalendarz k
         LEFT OUTER JOIN zamowienia z
                         on (MONTH(z.data_zlozenia) = MONTH(k.miesiace) AND YEAR(z.data_zlozenia) = YEAR(k.miesiace))

         LEFT OUTER JOIN zamowienia_pozycje zp on (z.id_ezamowienia = zp.id_ezamowienia AND zp.id_artykulu = 9593)

WHERE k.miesiace >= DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 12 MONTH)
  AND k.miesiace <= now()

GROUP BY MONTH(k.miesiace), YEAR(k.miesiace)
ORDER BY YEAR(k.miesiace), MONTH(k.miesiace);
```

Comment: It also works. Thank You so much for the answer. All the best!

Answer (score 1):

`zp` is left joined so adding this where clause:

```
AND zp.id_artykulu = 9593
```

will turn the query into kind of an inner join... rows from `kalendarz` table will be suppressed if there is no match in the right table. Move the condition to the `on` clause:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN zamowienia_pozycje zp on z.id_ezamowienia = zp.id_ezamowienia and zp.id_artykulu = 9593
```

Comment: Thank You very much for explanation! All the best!